# Will threading affect image processing performance on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I work on a project about autonomous vehicle. In this project, there is real time video processing on Raspberry Pi (model 3B) using Opencv 4.0 in C++. There iş also a distnace sensor at the front of the vehicle which distance to a casual obstacle. The task is to stop the car if there is an obstacle within 1 meter.

To realize this task I though to employ a threading in my programming structure. I designed image processing as main thread and distance sensor measurement as a side thread. What I am concerned is that would this structure effect image processing speed or not. Do you have any idea? Besides I wonder if main thread uses 4 cores of the Raspberry Pi? If so, would introducing a thread into structure split core as 3 to image processing and 1 to distance sensor measurement?

I am quit confused about this. The design in my head can be seen in the snippet below (Note that main thread loops infinitely):

```
int measuredDistance;
int distanceThreshold = 1; // 1 meter

void * sensor_thread(void * threadid) {
   // measure distance
   // update measuredDistance 
}

int main () {
   while(1){
      // do image processing
      if (measuredDistance < distanceThreshold)
         stopTheCar();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At first you have to have a problem at hand, which can be split into sub-problems. Image-processing is such a problem. So good for you, you can think about splitting your problem.

Is your system able to execute more then 1 thread at a time - multicore, multithread or hyperthread or what ever. If I understand you correctly, your Pi can handle up to 4 threads at a time. This is good and you are set for a multithreading program.

Answering your the question: Does the main thread use all 4 cores? Basically no, the main thread is only one thread, which runs on one core. Your measuring thread will run on another core.

So you want to split your image-processing into threads. You will see nearly no improvement, when you just put your image-processing into one extra thread apart your main thread. You have to split your image into parts and put them into at least TWO threads. I would suggest a generic approach, where can easily change the thread count, so you can experiment, what is the fastest setup.

I short, you can't expect an clear answer from us. It depends on your implementation and on your system, what else it has to do and where you data is store... and so on and so on... BUT if you read into some good books and choose wisely in how to implement your image-processing, I would expect an performance improvement.

If you are good with estimations, there is a mathematical approach. This is explained in more detail in this [LINK](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Estimating-CPU-Performance-using-Amdahls-Law-619/).

Parallelization Formula:

```
S(n) = 1/( (1-P) + P/n )
```

- S(n) is the theoretical speedup
- P is the fraction of the algorithm that can be made parallel
- n is the number of CPU threads

> What this is basically saying is that the amount of speedup a program will see by using n cores is based on how much of the program is serial (can only be run on a single CPU core) and how much of it is parallel (can be split up among multiple CPU cores).

Comment: As I see, adding a measurement thread won't effect the image processing performance, since image processing runs on 1 core and there are 3 cores left for other threads. But as a general speed for the all processes, splitting image processing into threads will help regarding total loop time?

Comment: If you split up your algorithm or data right, you will find yourself with a nice speedup. Yes.